# How to generate files in a docker container for having the same owner as the host's user

Tags: linux, git, docker, development-environment, devtools

I use docker containers to get some development tasks done in my git repositories.

The containers I use are built specifically for each project, that way each contributor only need docker CLI to get things done.

The bad side is the container run as root, thus generated files are owned by root once the container stops, and that's bad..

I can't change the owner in the container before exiting because there isn't the required user in the container /etc/passwd file.

I would create a user in the container before compiling the docker image but then the container won't be universal (for all my dev team).

What is the best practice(s) about that ?

Comment: `docker run -u username`

Comment: @TJBiddle Just running the command you suggest cause errors like `docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user PASSED_USERNAME: no matching entries in passwd file.` It is what I speak about in the 4th paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a new `dockerfile` in the repository which is based on the former image (pre-installed with devtools but with no user created but root).

In a such `dockerfile`, write something like the following:

```
FROM <ABSTRACT_FORMER_IMAGE>
ARG username=developer
RUN useradd -r -u 1001 -g $username $username
USER $username
```

Then, before starting to work, each developer in the team should use the dockerfile to build its own base image for new project+developer specific containers, passing its username.

```
$ docker build --build-arg username=$USER Dockerfile
```

Some better practices out there ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your user to the image, launch the container as root, and use an entrypoint to adjust the uid/gid inside the container to match that of the volume mounts from your devs. Then switch to your container user to run your app.

To implement this, I've used an entrypoint shell script that includes the following lines:

```
  OLD_UID=`getent passwd "${opt_u}" | cut -f3 -d:`
  NEW_UID=`ls -nd "$1" | cut -f3 -d' '`
  if [ "$OLD_UID" != "$NEW_UID" ]; then
    usermod -u "$NEW_UID" "$opt_u"
    if [ -n "$opt_r" ]; then
      find / -mount -uid "$OLD_UID" -exec chown "$opt_u" {} \;
    fi
  fi
  OLD_GID=`getent group "${opt_g}" | cut -f3 -d:`
  NEW_GID=`ls -nd "$1" | cut -f4 -d' '`
  if [ "$OLD_GID" != "$NEW_GID" ]; then
    groupmod -g "$NEW_GID" "$opt_g"
    if [ -n "$opt_r" ]; then
      find / -mount -gid "$OLD_GID" -exec chgrp "$opt_g" {} \;
    fi
  fi
```

In that script, `$1` is the volume mount path, `opt_u` is the username inside the container, `opt_g` is the group name, and `opt_r` is a flag to recursively adjust the filesystem inside the container.

At the very end of my entrypoint, I kick off:

```
exec gosu "${RUN_AS}" "$@"
```

Which switches to the user `$RUN_AS` and exec's the command passed to the entrypoint as that user, and as pid 1. Gosu is used to avoid `su` running as pid 1.

I've posted a similar example of this before with Jenkins as the app inside the container to match the GID of the docker socket. You can find the repo with all the steps here: https://github.com/bmitch3020/jenkins-docker

This has the significant upside of making the image portable to any developer system, and they can run it with the same command. Whatever the permissions are on the filesystem they map into the container from outside become the uid/gid of the user running commands inside the container. There's no need to lookup the local uid/gid on the developer system for your `docker run` command, or build your image on each developer workstation with unique uid/gid entries. The only downside of this implementation is that `docker exec` will enter the container as root, since you need to run your entrypoint as root for access to modify users/groups and filesystem ownership.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read this link to have the complete understanding of [docker privileges](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf) - and for you, the solution would be to run docker using --user command.

Comment: Thank you for the link that I'll read in deep. But your suggestion, using the `--user` CLI argument just return errors like `docker: Error response from daemon: linux spec user: unable to find user PASSED_USERNAME: no matching entries in passwd file.` It is what I speak about in the 4th paragraph of my question.